# How to reuse design from one .xib to another .xib?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I use .xib files for design

but most of my screens have the same structure, like 3 buttons and 2 label on top, remaining part is diff.

so I want to reuse buttons, labels from one .xib to another,

I have taken one parent-class for all similar screen so I created a label programatically in the parent-class which I can see in all its child class, but I want to do it using .xib

How can I use buttons in parent-class .xib to other child views?

I am doing that because I have the same header in 5 screens. header contains some buttons and labels, so I don't want to create the same design in each .xib

Comment: its not the way .xib works, make a controller with .xib which you can use into different controller as clid controller.

Comment: Thanks, yes I have controller with .xib, i have difficulty to reuse design in .xib to another screen

Comment: Just google to grasp the concept, start from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19826725/in-ios-using-storyboard-how-to-setup-a-view-controller-inside-a-container-view and http://sandmoose.com/post/35714028270/storyboards-with-custom-container-view-controllers

Answer (score 0):

NIB files (xib or storyboards) are not like cocoa-touch files. A nib file cannot be inherited or subclassed. Your option is to duplicate the original file and add your modifications manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the same .xib for ALL of the screens, but create properties/IBOutlets for the items you would like to change on each screen. Then simply change those items in the .m file at run time, rather than in the .xib itself.